# Jquery functions not working in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I wrote this code for a image navigation:

```
function buttons(){
    if($("#1").is(":visible")){
        $("#prev").hide();
    }else{
        $("#prev").show();
    }
    if($("#<?php echo $anzahl; ?>").is(":visible")){
        $("#next").hide();
    }else{
        $("#next").show();
    }
}
buttons();

function next(){
    var firstvisible = $(".thumbprofilpic:visible:first").attr("id");
    var lastvisible = $(".thumbprofilpic:visible:last").attr("id");
    var shownextpic = parseInt(lastvisible) + 1;
    var hideprevpic = parseInt(firstvisible);
    $('#' + hideprevpic).hide();
    $('#' + shownextpic).show();
    var selected = '<img src="' + $('#' + lastvisible).attr('src') + '">';
    var bild = selected.replace("/klein/", "/normal/");
    $("#previewprofil").html(bild);
    buttons();
}

function prev(){
    var firstvisible = $(".thumbprofilpic:visible:first").attr("id");
    var lastvisible = $(".thumbprofilpic:visible:last").attr("id");
    var showprevpic = parseInt(firstvisible) - 1;
    var hidenextpic = parseInt(lastvisible);
    $('#' + showprevpic).show();
    $('#' + hidenextpic).hide();
    var selected = '<img src="' + $('#' + firstvisible).attr('src') + '">';
    var bild = selected.replace("/klein/", "/normal/");
    $("#previewprofil").html(bild);
    buttons();
}

function picid(z){
    var selected = '<img src="' + $(z).attr('src') + '">';
    var bild = selected.replace("/klein/", "/normal/");
    $("#previewprofil").html(bild);
}
```

It works in chrome, safari, opera and firefox but not in IE (ofc, i'm getting sick of this POS) Can someone tell me how to edit this code to get it work with this plague?

Comment: What doesn't work? What part? What error do you get?

Comment: Well picid(z) works fine but nothing else, where can I see errors?

Comment: Open up the F12 Developer tools and look at the console.

Comment: Ok I did but don't get any errors, the console stays clear

Comment: You are going to have to step through your code to get any answers. I can't debug for you. My guess is that one of the selectors isn't working correctly, but debug, find out exactly what isn't working, and we can help you with that.

Comment: I'll try, just thought maybe here is someone with much experience with ie

Comment: I have lots, but until I know what you are struggling with I can't suggest a fix.

Comment: I alerted alert("test"); at the end of buttons() and it works, then I tryed to alert it at the start of next() but it's not working, so next() don't even start. Then I added a yellow background to the "next" div and it worked, so I added background: url("/pics/leer.png") 0 0 repeat; to this div because this way helped with another problem but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `background-color: yellow; filter:alpha(opacity=60); opacity:.0;`to the `next` and `prev` divs -.-